# Php double number precision sum from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, double

I have a number in a MySQL table, which is `0.000102`.

This number is then multiplicated .8 which gives `0.0000816`, BUT the result is then `8.16E-5`.

My formula is this:

```
function fixRendiconto($valore, $percent = 1){
    $valore = str_replace(",", ".", $valore);
    if($percent == 1 || $valore < 0){
        $elabora = ($valore == '') ? '0.00' : (double)str_replace(",", ".", $valore);
    }else{
        $elabora = ($valore == '') ? '0.00' : (double)str_replace(",", ".", $valore);
        $elabora = $elabora*(double)$percent;
    }
    return $elabora;
}

fixRendiconto(0.000102, .80);
```

How do I get the result `0.0000816` or even longer number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all intents and purposes except for display to humans, `8.16E-5` is perfectly fine (that's not how the number is stored internally, fyi).

If you want to display the number for human reading, format it as a string:

```
number_format($elabora, 7); // 7 is the amount of decimal places
```

Again, this will return a string, which will make calculations impossible (thus it should be done for display only, or as after all of your calculations etc.). Read more: https://www.php.net/number_format